# what is the difference between '$x_at' and 'x', (Labeling) in qgis?

Tags: qgis, labeling

In properties > Label > placement > data defined > coordinates:

'x'... when I move the label manually,
but what is '$x_at' for? Do they have a huge difference?

Comment: Have you actually tried reading the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'X' Returns the x coordinate of a point geometry, or the x-coordinate of the centroid for a non-point geometry.

'$x_at (i)' Retrieves a x coordinate of the current feature's geometry where 'i' is the index of point of a line (indices start at 0; negative values apply from the last index), so $x_at(1) returns the x coordinate of the second vertice of the line